# How to open a Symfony app on production mode [url]

Tags: symfony, host, production

How can I test my app in production mode, when I try to open it http://localhost/FirstProject/Symfony/web/app_prod.php/
the server returns `Not Found`

Comment: My symfony2 app :) thanks

Comment: try http://localhost/FirstProject/Symfony/web/app.php/

Comment: yes they work thanks :)